# Enable element on click event when ionic loading show

Tags: ionic-framework, loading, pointer-events

I want to make menu button at the top left corner in my app can be clicked when ionic loading show, I have move back drop margin to make menu button not overlapped by ionic loading backdrop, here is my code :

```
.backdrop {
    margin-top:50px;
}

.loading {
    pointer-events:auto;
}
```

Here is one of my code to call ionic loading in app.js :

```
$ionicLoading.show({
    template: 'Loading Data'
});
```

I have also set pointer-events to auto, but my button menu can't be clicked, anybody can help ?

Comment: Can you also share any relevant html and/or js?

Comment: In my html or js I didn't do anything to make menu button can be clicked, I just wonder somebody can tell me how to make any element can be clicked when Ionic loading show.. @IsaiahGrey

Comment: The possible solution is too add the element that you wish to be able to click into the loading template itself. You could trigger the menu from that template instead of embedding it outside(or both).

Comment: The `template` can take a html string, or you could use the `templateUrl` and embed a template which may be easier to manage as far as styling the whole component.